# Can I run PHP code in Javascript without using AJAX?

Tags: php, javascript

How to convert JavaScript variable to php variable without using of AJAX inside the JavaScript function.

```
 function getProduct(category)
{
    document.galaxy.action = '<?php echo JRoute::_('index.php?option=com_virtuemart&view=category&virtuemart_category_id=11') ?>';
    document.getElementById('galaxy').submit();
}
```

I need to convert js variable "category" to php variable.

Comment: That'll not work, JavaScript is parsed on the client side _after_ it is parsed by PHP and the Apache.

Answer (score 1):

This is **not** posible.

**Javascipt** is an client-side language, this means that its going to run on the computer of your visitor.

**PHP** is an server-side language, this means that is going to run on your server.

Answer (score 0):

You can't. What happens when a site is viewed:

1. PHP executes all PHP code on the server
2. The Webserver sends the site to the client
3. The client browser executes JavaScript

When you want use a JavaScript variable with PHP, you have so send it back to the server in some way (AJAX).

Answer (score -1):

```
var DivVal=document.getElementById('ChkStatus');
       //var InnerVal=DivVal.innerHTML;
       var editRedirect='<?php echo $this->createUrl("Employee/Print"); ?>';
       window.location=editRedirect;
```

Comment: When answering by code sample please explain what it does.

Answer (score -2):

As other people mentioned, you are misunderstanding the concepts a little.

If you want something from your JS sent along with the form to your PHP script you should put it in a form field.

in your form use a hidden value:

```
<input type="hidden" id="categoryInput" name="category" />
```

in your JS:

```
//Before you submit do this..
document.getElementById('categoryInput').value = category;
```

in your PHP:

```
$category = $_REQUEST['category'];
```

**EDIT:**

Seems like you are asking for this:

```
document.galaxy.action = '<?php echo JRoute::_('index.php?option=com_virtuemart&view=category') ?>&virtuemart_category_id=' + category;
```